# How to disable default code reviews values in Gerrit Jenkins trigger?

Tags: jenkins, gerrit, gerrit-trigger

In Gerrit Jenkins trigger,I do not want to send default values of code review set by Gerrit admin. How can I do that ?

I am giving no values in my projects under code review section but still Jenkins is sending code review values in gerrit.

Under "Gerrit event", "Advanced" there are options for code review, but I don't know what to enter in the box to say "don't do anything"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put 0 in the following attributes

Successful
Failed
Unstable

Then will looks like do nothing.

Br,

Tim